# ffmpeg: How to create a video from images with different delay between the images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I grabbed a quantity of snapshots at **irregular times** and would like to create a posthumous (fake) real-time video (mp4, animated GIF, etc) from them. This means **I need to insert a proper delay between these frames, and this dwell time changes between each couple of frames**.

As an example:

- frame0, taken at t0;
- frame1, taken at t1=1 sec;
- frame2, at t2=5 sec;
- end dwell time of 2 seconds

should return a 7-sec video like this:

[image: example_video]

I cannot afford to work manually with a video editing software because we are talking about hundreds of frames, but I can easily prepare a list with all frame names and delays between them.

I read around how to create a video with a **fixed** interframe time (i.e. from [here](https://linuxhint.com/ffmpeg_images_to_video_tutorial/)), how to [create animated GIFs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python) (alas with fixed delay), and how to [add a frame at the end of an existing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811800/using-ffmpeg-to-add-a-single-frame-to-end-of-mp4) (the dwell time between second-last and last frame can be set, but the process is very inefficient and slow for hundred of frames).

Can it be done with ffmpeg or any other Linux tool?

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer

Comment: It is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you, I would have never found it. Please publish your comment as an answer (it would be better to copy the text instead of a link that can be lost in the future), so I can upvote it.

Comment: this is dead :(
Please don't share links, share the method instead.

Comment: Gyan's link is yet active.